# Image convert S3

Tags: image, amazon-s3, metadata

I manually uploaded an image to my aws account in an S3 bucket. Now I need inside a lambda to retrieve this image with the getObject method and extract the metadata from that image. I'm not getting it because what returns from S3 is an object and not an image. Can someone help me ?